# convert an Array[(Any, (Any, Any))] to spark dataframe with 2 columns

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an array of type `Array[(Any, (Any, Any))]` which I want to convert to a spark `dataframe` such that the first value comes in first column and the tuple comes in the second column.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am not able to change this type of array as it is of type Any. I have tried converting it to sequence also.

Comment: You should probably first fix the Array to not contain `Any` types since Spark columns can not be `Any`. How is the array created?

Answer (score 1):

First of all `DataFrame` object has a strong schema - you can convert your `RDD` or `Seq` to a `DataFrame` implicitly, but it *will* attach a strong schema to your collection. Since `Any` type is just a way of saying *I don't know what my type is*, you will have to cast it to some specific type before you make it a part of a `DataFrame`.

Assuming you would convert everything to `String`:

```
import spark.implicits._
val df  = Array.empty[(Any, (Any, Any))]
  .map{case (first, (second, third)) => 
       (first.toString, (second.toString, third.toString))
  }.toSeq.toDF

df.printSchema
```

gives

```
root
 |-- _1: string (nullable = true)   
 |-- _2: struct (nullable = true)  
 |    |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val arr: Array[(Int, (Int, Int))] = Array((1,(2,3)), (4,(5,6)))
spark.createDataFrame(arr).show()
```

Which get the dataframe as:

```
+---+-----+
| _1|   _2|
+---+-----+
|  1|[2,3]|
|  4|[5,6]|
+---+-----+
```

or you can custom column info as:

```
spark.createDataFrame(arr, schema：StructType)
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: that is not the schema of array . It is of Any type . I am getting this error

    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Any is not supported

Comment: schema is not array, is StructType, or you can use spark.createDataFrame(arr).withColumnRenamed("_1", "a").withColumnRenamed("_2", "b")